# EF Code First error in WPF application

Tags: entity-framework

We use EF and I'm trying to query the database in this way:

```
using (var ctx = contextFactory.CreateContext())
{
    InspectionListByYear = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<List<string>>(@"select YEAR(EndDate) from Diagnostics as d inner join EquipmentDiagnostics as ed
        on d.Id = ed.Diagnostics_Id where d.Discriminator LIKE '%VisualCheck%' and ed.Equipment_Id = 7 group by DATEPART(yyyy, EndDate)");
}

public List<string> InspectionListByYear
{
    get { return _inspectionListByYear; }
    set
    {
        if (Equals(value, _inspectionListByYear))
            return;

        _inspectionListByYear = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => InspectionListByYear);
    }
}
```

But, the complier error was raised:

```
Error   134 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbRawSqlQuery<System.Collections.Generic.List<string>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'  D:\Repositories\Dev\Eam\Src\Modules\VisualCheck\VisualCheckAnalysis\VisualCheckAnalyzerViewModel.cs 77  40  VisualCheckAnalysis
```

How to overcome this error?

Comment: The generic argument of `SqlQuery` is the **element type**. Change `SqlQuery<List<string>>` to `SqlQuery<string>` and add `ToList()` at the end.

Comment: I've already tried it, but got this run time error: The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Int32' type to the 'System.String' type is not valid.

Comment: Well, that means the query returns `int`s which you need to convert to `string`s using regular LINQ, e.g. use `SqlQuery<int>` and add at the end `Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList()`

Comment: If you write this as separated comment I'll check it as correct answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `SqlQuery` method always returns enumerable sequence, the generic type argument (btw called `TElement`) represents the type of the element of that sequence, not the type of the result.

So `SqlQuery<List<string>>` call is incorrect. According to the SQL, the query is returning a set with a single field coming from `YEAR` T-SQL function, so the element type should be `int`.

Now, having basically `IEnumerable<int>`, to get a desired `List<string>` you can use regular LINQ `Select` to perform the `int` to `string` conversion combined with `ToList` call:

```
InspectionListByYear = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<int>(@"select YEAR(EndDate) from Diagnostics as d inner join EquipmentDiagnostics as ed
    on d.Id = ed.Diagnostics_Id where d.Discriminator LIKE '%VisualCheck%' and ed.Equipment_Id = 7 group by DATEPART(yyyy, EndDate)")
    .Select(x => x.ToString())
    .ToList();
```